# How to work with Ansible on a single host?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to learn Ansible. Almost all the documents, tutorials, blogs that I come across are talking about provisioning, config management across multiple server etc etc.

I have a single Windows system(laptop) and I have VirtualBox with several Linux VMs. I want to know how to play with Ansible on a single system.

Does Ansible needs multiple machines to play with?

I am new to all these ConfigManagement tools and System Administration stuff.

So, can anyone please explain how to get started with Ansible on a Single System?

PS: Just after posting this question I came across https://sysadmincasts.com/episodes/43-19-minutes-with-ansible-part-1-4 which explains very well what I am looking for.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a comment why downvote so that I can improve question or realize what I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install Ansible on a Linux VM (see [installation manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html); you'll need Python and a couple of dependencies) or run a dockerized Ansible on your Windows host (find a suitable image, for example the [official one](https://hub.docker.com/r/ansible/ansible/)).
2. Login to the machine you installed Ansible on and create a playbook (save the following to a file named `hello.yml`)

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: localhost

     connection: local

     tasks:
       - debug: msg="Hello World!"
   ```
3. Run the playbook:

   ```
   ansible-playbook hello.yml
   ```
4. Check the result (there will be a few warnings):

   ```
   PLAY [localhost] 

   ***************************************************************

   TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "msg": "Hello World!"
   }

   PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
   ```

You are running Ansible on a single host now.

Head for the manuals at [docs.ansible.com](https://docs.ansible.com/) to learn what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for detailed instructions. I have dual boot, switched to LinuxMint and made it as Ansible control host and trying to use couple of Ubuntu VMs as nodes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by single system? In Ansible, you have one control host (where Ansible is installed) and one or more multiple remotes. Your Windows system can be a control host or one of your Virtual Box VMs can be a control host. As long as you have ssh access to a remote, you can control it from your Ansible host. What is your actual use case? You can use Ansible for a single system.

First install Ansible on the control host. Then you can run simple Ansible commands with target (remote) host as your VM(s).

Comment: After digging through some more documentation, I understand that I need a ControlHost which is *nix based on which Ansible has to be installed and we can manage one or more nodes which can be other physical machines or VMs. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k you can have Windows as control host using cygwin + ansible.